# How to estimate the amount of RAM it will take Encog to train a particular network with a particular sample set with Levenberg-Marquardt algorithm?

Tags: java, algorithm, neural-network, encog

I am studying Encog (versions 3.0 and 3.1 for Java) neural network framework and would like to try Levenberg–Marquardt algorithm in my neural network training. However my actual neural networks are pretty complex natural (featuring hundreds of input neurons) and not a single (I've been simplifying from tens of thousands to 136) network appears to be possible to be trained with Levenberg–Marquardt (saying there is not enough memory while I dedicate 2 GiBs to the JVM). But it performs very good when I try a simple synthetic task with a simple (just 3 input neurons) network.

The question is how can I estimate the amount of memory it will take Encog to train a particular network with a particular sample set with Levenberg-Marquardt algorithm? How can I guess what is the maximum complexity can be fit in 2 GiBs (the actual machine has 4, but the JVM seems unable to allocate more than 2)?

Comment: You have about 90 questions without an accepted answer.  Perhaps you can review some of the answers you have been given before.

Comment: I would guess it is O(N*K+N*N) from the wikipedia page (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenberg%E2%80%93Marquardt_algorithm). Where N is the number of training instances and K the number of weights. Usually you should worry more about time complexity when you train with huge data sets because LMA is in O(N**3). It is good for simple problems but when you apply ANNs to large scale problems you should prefer stochastic gradient descent or conjugate gradient.

Answer (score 5):

I would try a small size, determine how much memory it uses and keep doubling the size until you see a pattern. i.e. is it linear or super linear.

BTW: My TV has 4 GB of memory, perhaps its time to get more memory if you need it. ;)